# How to gauge how professional/formal to dress for a tenure track interview

Tags: tenure-track, interview, outward-appearance

Departments vary a lot by discipline when it comes to what is acceptable attire for men and women both on a day to day basis and at interviews.  Some demand a suit, while this would be ostentatious at others.  Whereas some wouldn't bat an eye at seeing a backpack at an interview, while others would sneer at anything that isn't a leather satchel.  For instance, I've been eyeing this convertible messenger/backpack like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=patagonia%20tres%20pack%20grey&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixsJe21PDjAhXLdN8KHTyyDwoQ_AUIESgC&biw=2160&bih=1237) for a job interview (in environmental sciences), but my colleague in the MedSci department says leather or nothing.  Are there any rules of thumb to determine what is and is not appropriate when interviewing at an institution whose office culture you're not familiar with?

Comment: The [tag:academic-dress] tag is specifically about cap-and-gown style outfits, not about dress more generally, so I removed that tag.

Comment: https://theprofessorisin.com/2017/08/23/lets-talk-backpacks/

Comment: Could the downvoter comment?

Comment: I left the URL, but dropped the hyperlink, reducing the spam-look

Comment: Why is this bag _techy_?

Comment: You seem to be looking to buy a large backpack specifically for job interviews. May I ask why? I feel like I am missing some context here, and given context this may turn out to be an X/Y problem.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: This seems either heavily out of date or heavily field-dependent (the author is an anthropologist). I have seen my share of job interviews, and I only ever remember one person lugging a briefcase in academia (and that person was known for this and doing it not just for job interviews; it's part of his unique style). If the main argument against backpacks is really "they make you look like you are still mentally a grad student", then there are enough arguments against briefcases on the same level (how about looking like an administrator, hardly a good look when hiring ...

Comment: ... is mostly decided by faculty?). The only non-falsifiable signal that carrying a briefcase can imply is grip strength, which is actually a useful health signal (it correlates surprisingly well with physical and mental health), but taking such a signal into account opens a huge can of ethical worms (disability and general discrimination issues). I would thus view a person advocating for a candidate based upon their briefcase as either being superficial or trying to hire on health; not a good view in either case.

Comment: What do established professors do at conferences in your field? If many carry backpacks (which I'm guessing they do), then I think it's okay for a job interview too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question, the answer strongly depends on individual preferences and the link seems like a spam.

Comment: @user2768 I said it is techy because it is a polyester canvas like material rather than leather, has contrasting stitching, and is produced by Patagonia (a well-known outdoors gear brand).

Comment: @xLeitix The slightly longer version of the story is that I'm on the market for a new everyday carry bag, but since I'll be on the job market in a year, figured I might as well be forward-looking and buy something that would be appropriate for job interviews as well.  Since this has hide-away straps and can also be used as a briefcase/messenger bag, I figured it might be able to pull double duty in that way, but wasn't sure it was appropriate for interviews.

Comment: @darijgrinberg this is a good point, thanks for pointing it out.  Just like it could be a bit much to wear a suit to an interview in some departments, it could equally be excessive to have a leather briefcase, for instance.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I can assure you it is not spam.  I am merely trying to determine the appropriateness of clothing for tenure track interviews, which varies significantly by field, as I understand it.

Comment: _I'm on the market for a new everyday carry bag_, I'd consider a backpack or a satchel appropriate for interview, conferences, day-to-day, ... A (suitable) satchel probably fits better with any type of clothing (including suits), in general, than a backpack does. Then again, it obviously varies, e.g., Samsonite is a brand picked by many executives. That said, you probably can't get (nor would you want) a 25L satchel.

Comment: @user2768, I've edited my question to seem less spam-like.  That said, I don't see this objection being raised on [this related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16486/what-to-wear-on-ones-shoulders-to-interviews-bags-backpacks-etc?rq=1), which is admittedly less specific but has the same tenor and topic.

Comment: @user2768 The word "techy" means "characteristic of the technology industry". The questioner appears to be asking in good faith, and I don't believe it is appropriate to accuse him/her of spamming.

Comment: @academic The question has been edited numerous times, the original looks like spam, take a look. (In addition to the reasons mentioned above, low user reputation was another reason.) Given the volume of comments the OP has made, I now believe the question was asked in good faith, I didn't when I made the comment. Regarding, _characteristic of the technology industry_, I don't see the bag as _techy_, under your definition. _Technical_ has a different meaning in the outdoor gear market.

Comment: Based on the edit, I have voted to reopen. I think there are useful rules of thumb.

Answer (score 10):

I have been on the hiring side of several dozen academic job interviews.  As such, I am somewhere between amused and alarmed that you think your bag will figure into the job selection process.  If your research concerns the bag or if you were giving your talk from inside the bag maybe -- otherwise, how does this even come up?

Preparing for job interviews is a good thing, but I advise you to concentrate your preparations on the things that could matter.  Perhaps you can further work on your slides or on some other aspect of your job talk.  Perhaps you could do further research into the faculty of the department and plan specific things to say to each of them.  And so forth.  These sorts of preparations are still unlikely to make a difference in the outcome...but more so than ruminating on your choice of bag.

Good luck.

Comment: To be fair math is probably all the way on one end of the spectrum here (with probably business schools on the other end).

Comment: Have you never considered factors like how well a candidate will "fit in" to your department or how "professional" they seemed? How do you think you intuited these things?

Comment: I agree with Pete here. At least in the searches I've been in, given the extreme competitiveness of funding and applicants nowadays, we are only concerned with getting the "superest" superstar from the pool. Also at my school they like to stick recent hires on the committees, so it would be biased the other way if anything.

Comment: @Dawn Exactly. Women also tend to get judged more harshly on superficialities, regardless of whether the people doing the judging are aware of it.

Comment: Your answer would be also appliciable to very unprofessional bags (such as very dirty ones with holes). Would you also sas that this makes no difference?

Comment: @user111388 I don't think a _very dirty [bag] with holes_ is necessarily unprofessional, by comparison a bag with an inappropriate slogan (e.g., racist, sexist, homophobic, ...) or design would be, and I believe such a bag would make a difference.

Comment: Yes, I understand this to be very field dependent, which is why I included the detail of my discipline.  For instance, my brother, who was a medical student, mentioned that he had to buy a leather briefcase, as anything else would look schlubby.  Also, your response is a false dilemma, one can be concerned with their appearances and still offer strong content.

@ASimpleAlgorithm, what do you mean by them being biased the other way?  That a more formal-looking briefcase or satchel would be seen as highfalutin?

Comment: @elduderino260 more broadly that conservative and businesslike attire might be as much of a "turn off" to young profs who are anything but conservative and businesslike, as they might help you with members of previous generations. At least to the degree that such things factor in either way, which is nada in my experience. I have seen candidates make opposing arguments regarding Trump to committee members at dinner, and still get offers.

Comment: @Dawn: We consider "fit" for the department based on interactions with the job candidate.  Moreover, when someone has been brought in for an interview, they are already the top choice of a certain subset of the faculty and have to compete against candidates who are the top choices of other subsets of the faculty.  Those in the middle have to be won over by arguments.  "His bag was better than hers" is a very strange argument.

Comment: @elduderino260: I take your point that my answer is coming from a mathematician, so maybe it would be good to get an answer from someone in your field.  But in terms of the "false dilemma": no, I don't think so.  You can't optimize **every single thing** in your job search.  Even if you could, some things are much more important than others, and you should spend your time accordingly.  It's not even clear to me who would see your bag in a job interview in any more than a passing way.  So (in my opinion, of course) thinking about this is really not helping you with your job search.

Comment: I don't think the point here is either about optimizing everything or about picking candidates based on their bag. "Fit" is a vague and potentially insidious criterion that includes things like how the candidate presents themselves, which includes what they wear and what they carry. No one passing bigoted and irrational judgments ever thinks that's what they are doing.